# How to check in wikipedia that a page is an article or not?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm retrieving metadata about multiple articles in Wikipedia through MediWikiAPI. The problem is that some pages are not articles. How can I check if a page with a specific title or URL is article or not?

Comment: What's your definition of an article? Just the namespace?

Comment: For example, a Disambiguation page is not an article

Comment: Then try filtering them by [their categories](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#categories_.2F_cl).

Comment: This is a possible solution, but how to get all "non-articles" categories?

Comment: You will need to curate that list by hand. For example, [Misspellings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Redirects_from_misspellings) might be another candidate (oh, wait, those are redirects only in the EN Wikipedia at least). It depends on what you need; there is no category of non-articles if you mean that. (And honestly, the categorisation system is a mess)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat depends on your definition, but [`meta=siteinfo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&meta=siteinfo&siprop=general%7Cnamespaces) can tell you which are the content namespaces and and [`prop=pageprops`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=pageprops&generator=random&ppprop=&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=10) includes `disambiguation` for such pages.